# VW Rabbit MK5 - Paint Peel On Bumper, Easy Fix?

Tags: vw, paint

Some paint is peeling on the front bumper of my 2007 VW Rabbit. 
[image]

Are there any fixes that can be done without replacing the full bumper or taking it into a body shop?

Comment: Peeling will continue, the bumper needs sanding and a re-paint complete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry to say that's pretty bad - you've lost not just the clear coat (lacquer) but the actual paint as well.

The good news is that because it's on the bumper (which is plastic) you aren't at any risk of rust as a result, it just looks awful. The bad news is that there's no easy DIY fix that's going to look much better. That's going to need spraying at a proper body shop I'm afraid - on the upside it doesn't look like it's going to need blending so it's just a blow over on the bumper itself so it shouldn't be ruinously expensive.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Any idea what decent prices for this kind of work go for? Like for about $120 CAD I can probably just find the part at a scrap yard so I'm wondering if taking it to a body shop is worth it.

Comment: @guy couldn't tell you prices in Canada I'm afraid (I'm in the UK). Certainly in the UK you'd struggle to get a quality paint job done on that for $120 CAD - I'd probably expect to pay at least double that. Swapping the bumper for one from a scrap yard is going to be tricky - even if you find one that's the matching paint code I think you're going to struggle to get a good match and it might just end up looking even worse.

Comment: Yeah seems like body work is very expensive. Honestly I don't find it difficult to find a matching part at a scrap yard. I've done it for my fenders and it was about $100 for a near perfect condition, paint matched fender. Maybe i was just lucky. So i will try to do the same for the bumper.